# Pass string value from broadcast receiver to a service

Tags: android

I want to pass a string value from broadcast receiver to a service.If someone could please illustrate with an example.
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your broadcast receiver write like this

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(context,UrService.class);
    intent.putExtra("stringdata","ur String value");
    context.startService(intent);

}
```

In your service class get the value like this

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
    String data=intent.getStringExtra("stringdata");
    // use this value as your wish
}
```

Comment: How do you make sure the service is registered for that intent?

Answer (score 0):

@prank you don't need to register the service to the intent, 
the receiver will be register to the intent, and then when the receiver get the call, it will start the service.
By doing this you pass the long task to the service and close the receiver since it can live only for sort time